# JavaScript not working after deployment

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

recently, I created an application wizard using a Bootstrap plugin (https://github.com/amoffat/bootstrap-application-wizard), which works fine when I just access the HTML file from my browser (Chrome).

Once I put the code into a new ASP.NET MVC4 view, include the stylesheets and js files (both in Visual Studio and the code as well), Chrome displays the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'wizard'
```

Here's the belonging part of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var wizard = $('#new-vm-wizard').wizard({
            keyboard: false,
            contentHeight: 400,
            contentWidth: 700,
            backdrop: 'static',

            buttons: {
                cancelText: "Abort",
                nextText: "Next",
                backText: "Back",
                submitText: "Submit",
                submittingText: "Please wait",
            }
        });
```

The weird part: Once I copy & paste the code back into a simple HTML file (and of course adapt the paths of the js/css files), I can again open the file with Chrome and the whole wizard works like a charm.

It can't be an including error either since Visual Studio allows me to quick-jump to all linked files without any problems.

Has someone experienced the same issue before? I'm thankful for any kind of advice since this thing is driving me really crazy.

Regards,
fabs

Comment: show your <script> tag(s) -- likely the problem is the path

Comment: Sorry, forgot those. There you go: http://pastebin.com/Ax4N0iH8
I just used drag and drop from the project explorer to embed the files.

Comment: when you deploy the asp.net application, your script tags must be pointing to the right location (relative/or based off root) -- you should do as Naveed recommends,  I use Firebug with network monitoring:  https://getfirebug.com/network  using this, you can see if the browser's requests for the js files (and css files) succeed or fail.  Chances are they are failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery.tools.js seems to be responsible for the issues. Since I thought it's a dependency of bootstrap-wizard.js, I didn't try to run the code without it. After removing the correspondent script tag, everything works. I don't understand why it worked in a static HTML file though...
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

use chrome debugger or your favourite debugger to make sure that your source file is pulled out. also make sure that you are NOT referencing the source file more then once

Comment: I removed some double references for Bootstrap, but the error remains. http://s1.directupload.net/images/140210/ftko4wqs.png
edit: Removing the browser cache only causes the status code to change to 200.